# Are 2x6 joists adequate for a loft spanning 10 feet?

Tags: framing, attic, load-bearing, engineering

Planning to build a 10'x16' "cabin" with a loft. My idea is to use 2x4-10 for the walls then in the loft area use 2x4-8 for the walls and run 2x6-10 the width of the cabin to create the loft floor joists. Do I need additional posts or beams for support or am I just totally going about this the wrong way?

The loft should be able to support two sleeping adults and a mattress. I'm new to all of this so trying to keep it stupid simple.

- the cabin will sit on concrete pillar and beam foundation
- ground snow load in the area is ~100 psf
- the soil is loam

[image]

Comment: Will you be getting a permit and hooking up to a power company?

Comment: https://www.plib.org/aitc/resources/publications/beam-capacity-tables/

Comment: I will not be hooking up to a power company (not available). Permit is TBD but I probably should.

Comment: @Ruskes every floor joist of the loft has to be 3.5" width? I am having a hard time interpreting the table you linked.

Comment: There is explanation at the bottom of the table

Comment: What type of wood are you planning on using and what is the spacing between loft joists?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean happy to space them as close as I need to and use high grade lumber. Looking for guidance.

Comment: @Foopysfarm So, sheet of plywood on top of the loft joists and then a mattress?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean correct

Comment: @Ruskes, all your comments should be in your _answer_, not here.

Comment: For the use anticipated use, I'd say 2x4 joists with a plywood skin would be entirely sufficient. You could also greatly simplify the design by dispensing with the 8' studs, running a ledger 2x4 around the inside of the 10' studs either under the joists or inline and using hangers. It seems folks here like to grossly overbuild and complicate things.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the approach I would take.

1. Buy 2x6x10 SPF heat treated/kiln dried lumber

   - standard stuff stocked at big box stores should be fine; #2 or better
   - try to find the better ones in the stack with little warpage; no splits and avoid large knots on the edges
2. All joists should be crowned up and securely attached at the ends to studs
3. install the joist at the front as a double (beam); when people go up and down all their weight will initially be on that one beam with little spread to the next.
4. The joist at the back should additionally be screwed to the wall studs.
5. I would space the joists at 12"; 16" would be fine as well, but would definitely flex more and the 12" provides more even support for the plywood. I used an online sag calc as a [reference](https://www.mycarpentry.com/joist-span-table.html).
6. I would glue (construction adhesive) and screw 3/4"  plywood/OSB (2" long construction screws) down to the deck of the loft; the glue will prevent squeaks and help stiffen the whole thing.

   - If you can't buy a single sheet to fit this space, use 3/4" tongue and groove OSB and take advantage of the T&G to lock the pieces together.

Comment: It should be noted that joist hangers are typically a requirement. Otherwise you'll have _balloon framing_, which is generally prohibited in the 21st century.

Comment: I do like the 12" interval suggestion. I generally don't consider 2x6 adequate for joists spanning more than about 6 feet (regardless of load tables, due to bounce), so that would help.

Comment: @isherwood Joist hangers are typically required where the are not resting on bearing material; since the OP has a double plate below it, I see no reason to not run the joists onto it and let the double plate bear the weight of the loft. And as far as I know, balloon framing is still legal as long as there are fire stops between floors, which really isn't a concern here as it is a single level and the double plate already provides a fire block.

Comment: You're right. Apparently I misinterpreted the plan.

Comment: Since the outer edge of the wall is flush with the rim joist the overall width is 10' 3". This means the loft floor joists can't span the full width and would overlap the walls double top plate by 2" and not the full 3.5". Is this an issue?

Comment: @Foopysfarm You stated your cabin dimensions were 16'x10'; that sounds inaccurate from what you just stated. Why would the rim joist not be sitting on the foundation/piers? It sounds like you have a design problem as your walls are only half supported to the foundation. I've never heard/seen a rim joist not sitting on the sill plate. StackExchange is not meant to be a chatroom; you should ask a new question specifically about your pier/foundation design and first floor plans and provide exact dimensions.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean understood. I'll do some research and post a new question if I can't figure it out. You're right that 10' isn't accurate because it's 2x6x10' plus the rim joist on each end so it's 10'3". The rim joist sit on top of the beams that are on the foundation piers and are inset a few inches.

Answer (score 0):

If you put 1/2 inch or 3/4 inch plywood, that floor can carry up to 300 pounds per square foot with the proposed joists spaced at 16 or no more than 24 inch.